# Heroku App, Created File with Python, how can I get the download url?

Tags: javascript, html, file, heroku, download

with my Flask App I created some files to the heroku filesystem.
I know that the files are deleted by each dyno restart.

In my html/javascript frontend I want to download it now via button.

The question is, how can I get the download url of these files in the heroku filesystem?

Thank you!

Comment: Does the app create files? Or do they already exist when your app starts? If your code creates the files, surely you wrote something to save it - in which case you would have to provide the filepath that the file will be saved at.

Comment: It is in the root folder...shall I save it in /app ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Regardless of where you save it, the user needs to be able to go to a URL which points to the file. You should also create a separate upload directory (NOT root folder because that would let an attacker download every file off the server). Take a look at this: https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/flask.send_from_directory.html. In the @app.route, you can specify some URL pattern to give the user, and then in the actual function itself, it's just one line of code telling flask to retrieve and send the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for my problem:

Python:

```
@app.route("/test", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
if request.method == "POST":
    print("hello1")

    f = open("myfile.txt", "w")
    f.write("content")
    f.close()

    f = open("myfile.txt", 'r')

return json.dumps({'success': True, 'data': f.read()}), 200, {'ContentType': 
'application/json'}
```

Javascript:

```
$.ajax('/test', {
type: 'POST',
data: { myData: product},
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data, status, xhr) {
    console.log('response')

    console.log(data)

    console.log(data['success'])

    var bytes = new Uint8Array(data['data']); // pass your byte response to this constructor

    var blob=new Blob([data['data']], {type: "text/plain"});// change resultByte to bytes
      
    var link=document.createElement('a');
    link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download="myfile.txt";
    link.click();

    },
    error: function (jqXhr, testStatus, errorMessage) {
        console.log("error")
    }
});
```